# Angular login with google need to send response_type=code (Cannot set response_type=code with angularx-social-login)

Tags: angular, google-api, google-signin

I'm integrating Google authentication for login. I need to pass `response_type=code` to the API to receive code in the response as mentioned below:

```
{"code":"4/yU4cQZTMnnMtetyFcIWNItG32eKxxxgXXX-Z4yyJJJo.4qHskT-UtugceFc0ZRONyF4z7U4UmAI"}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `offline_access: true` instead of `response_type: 'code'`. I was struggling with the same problem, so I searched the library code. In case of sending `offline_access: true`, the response will contain the `authorizationCode` key.